# display data without authentication couchdb

Tags: authentication, couchdb

In couchDb > database > permissions add _admin in Roles and all works fine with add username and password in URL but for the download the attachment purpose I don't wont to add username and password in display curl.

so I want remove authentication only in display data. How can I do that ?

example:

1) http://username:password@127.0.0.1:5984/database/001
FOR add,delete,update

2) http://127.0.0.1:5984/database/001/test.php
FOR only display or download attachment.

Answer (score 1):

To provide an *everyone can read only a few can write pattern*<sup>1</sup>, you want to use a validate_update_doc<sup>2</sup> function in a design document.  The function is called for any request to create, update or delete a document.

For example required admin role to modify but allow anyone to read the database:

```js
function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx) {
  if (userCtx.roles.indexOf("_admin") === -1) {
    throw( { forbidden : "Only admins can modify the database." } );
  }
}
```

The design document might look like this

```
{
  "_id": "_design/validate_write",
  "validate_doc_update": "function (newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx) { if (userCtx.roles.indexOf('_admin') === -1) throw( { forbidden : 'Only admins can modify the database.'} ); }" 
}
```

It's easy to create this document in Fauxton.  As is outlined by both references, this may be extended to user roles etc.

Please note for your scenario you must set the CouchDB configuration property `require_valid_user`<sup>3</sup> to false.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>CouchDB authentication recipes: [Everybody can read only some can write](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication/blob/master/docs/recipes.md#everybody-can-read-only-some-can-write-everything)</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>CouchDB [validate_doc_update](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/ddocs.html#validate-document-update-functions) function</sub>

<sup>3</sup> <sub>CouchDB [require_valid_user configuration property](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/auth.html#authentication-configuration)</sub>

Comment: @KrunalPandya if you are asking where **to** put the code, it goes along with the design document.  Put the design document into the database.  Read the links I posted it should be clear.

Comment: I am trying to something in direct to DB.